# Time complexity of getting $r$-largest eigenvalues and vectors of a symmetric matrix.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computational-complexity, matrix-decomposition

$A$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix.
I would like to know the time complexity of calculating $r$-largest eigenvalues and vectors.

When we need all eigenvalues and eigenvectors, it means $r=n$, I think the time complexity is known as $O(n^3)$. I would like to know the case of $r<n$.

Answer (score 0):

Restricting the number of eigenvalues doesn't buy you much. You're really looking at slightly-worse than $O(m^{\omega})$, where $\omega$ is the exponent of Matrix Multiplication.

Note that what you get is an approximation of the eigenvalues, due to the nature of floating-point arithmetic (i.e., writing down the eigenvalues in binary on a Turing Machine).

[1] https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/complexity-of-finding-the-eigendecomposition-of-a-matrix

[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.08805

Comment: Thank you for your answer. SVD of n×m matrix for l-largest singular values needs O(nml). But you said, the computational complexity of eigenvalue decomposition for l-lagest eigenvalues does not depend on l. Where does the difference between eigenvalue decomposition and SVD come from?